# How to auto dismiss FCM notifications?

Tags: android

More specifically, I want the notification not to show/display/popup up in the notification bar, but devices do receive messages. I found not official APIs on firebase messaging.

Is there a solution for it? Thanks advanced!

Comment: pass the notification as data payload on Firebase. you can handle it programmatically. so ,you don't need to show the notification popups anything else.